# Brownsville Texas: will cabs take you over the Mexico border?

Tags: international-travel, borders, mexico, taxis, texas

Are there cab companies in Brownsville, TX that make drop offs and  pick ups of passengers across the border in Matamoros?

Comment: Don't understand the downvote. This seems like a great question to me.

Comment: @pnuts: Recommend muting your speakers before clicking that link.

Answer (score 7):

It does appear to be possible.

[RometoRio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Brownsville/Heroica-Matamoros) cites the cost as being $15-17, and will take approximately 5 minutes between the towns.

And  [Yellow Cab Taxi in Brownsville](http://www.taxibrownsville.com/) offers "Trips to Mexico" as part of their service.

> Service to Matamoros, Los Fresnos, Rancho Viejo